# SqlBulkCopy - InvalidOperationException - Which field is causing this

Tags: c#, .net, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using the SqlBulkCopy class to insert a DataSet into a pair of tables on my SQL Server database.

Sometimes the input data cannot be readily converted into the data type required by the target column. This results in an InvalidOperationException with the following description:

The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type smalldatetime of the specified target column.

The InnerException says: `Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.`

I have multiple DateTime fields in my table; how can I find out which field is causing the exception?

Comment: You should show your code

Comment: Hi Jens, just to clarify: my problem is not finding out why this is raising an exception. What I want is a way to find out, whenever at any point in the life of this code an exception of this type is raised, which field is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to convert the data yourself before adding it to the `DataSet`. That should highlight the dodgy data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this. This will allow me to actually present a usable message to the users of my system.

Answer (score 1):

For this task maybe you should use SQL Integration Services. With it, you can redirect the offending rows to a file for correction, among other features that will make your job more easy.

See this: http://redmondmag.com/articles/2010/04/12/log-error-rows-ssis.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to divide an conquer. Do test inserts with missing columns untill you have isolated the column or create a select using the isdate function (and any others if it might be an out of date range issue to find which columns or rows are at issue

Comment: +1, you can also play with `SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize`, `SqlBulkCopy.NotifyAfter` and `SqlBulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied` to try to identify the first row that exhibits the problem and then inspect the row.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few months back. The way I got around it was to make sure that my DataSet only had one record in it for testing and then set all of the DateTime strings to be a simple date (e.g. 01/01/2000). If you are still getting the error then it will be down to the format of the DateTime field in the database versus the format in the string at a general level as opposed to a single date in the string.

In my case it was due to good old fashioned UK and US date formats! My database was using UK, but some of the string dates were using US formatting.

Comment: Thats because your very close to Japan and they do have a consistent lsb to msb convention